# Private sales store redirecting to public store in magento

Tags: magento-1.8, multistore, php-5.4

From the admin panel I have created a private sales store successfully and a **Private Welcome page** is automatically created on `CMS->Pages->Managecontent` section, when I Clicked on it or when I enter `magento/private-sales` it's showing the private website. From that page we have a Login link and when I click on that it's redirecting to the default main website i.e., `magento/customer/account/login` i think it has to redirect to url `magento/private-sales/customer/account/login`?

It needs to any other settings to perform all private sale website actions?

Can you guys please let me know exact steps to get the expected, please provide help on this?

Comment: Finally I have achieved it, thanks for all. answer is not required...

Comment: Can you share your findings?

Comment: @Amasty, see below article easy to setup private sales with out extension.. http://www.opensourceforwebtechnologies.com/how-to-createset-up-and-manage-multiple-stores/